# how to join and search all the fields in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I have two documents product and seller.

Product: {ID,NAME,DESCRIPTION}
Seller: {ID, PRODUCT_ID, SELLER_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_VALUE}

I need to join both of these documents and search all the fields in the seller and product?

So far I'm trying something like {!join from=product_id to=id}seller_name:"Sample-2" . This searches value "Sample-2" in seller_name field of seller document.  How can i modify this to search all the fields of product and seller along with join?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you'd implement this by either using copyField-directives to add all the terms into one field and search on that field, or by supplying a qf= parameter to give the fields you'd want to search (with *dismax).

If you're going to do a lot of these you might want to create a separate core and index pre-processed data into that, with copyField directives to create a catch all-field.